# store data into mongodb in java

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I parse files and retrieves their contained then try to store them in my database with morphia, but i have this error:

```
INFO: LoggerImplFactory set to org.mongodb.morphia.logging.jdk.JDKLoggerFactory
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/client/model/geojson/codecs/GeoJsonCodecProvider
```

here is my main :

```
finally {


                    Morphia morphia =new Morphia(); 
                    String mongo2 ="test";
                    CelluDAO cellDAO=new CelluDAO(MongoUtil.getMongo(),morphia,mongo2);
                    System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");

                    for (Cellu cel : data) {
                        System.out.println(cel.getT());
                        cellDAO.save(cel);
                    }


                     MongoUtil.getMongo().close();
                }
```

here is my class CelluDAO :

```
public class CelluDAO extends BasicDAO<Cellu,String> {

    public CelluDAO (MongoClient mongoClient, Morphia morphia, String dbName) {
        super(mongoClient, morphia, dbName);
    }

public List<Cellu> findAll() {
    return ds.find(Cellu.class).asList();

}
public List<Cellu> findUnderID(int id){
    return ds.find(Cellu.class).filter("Id",id).order("Id").asList();
}

}
```

my class Mongoutil :

```
public class MongoUtil {
        private static final int port = 27017;
        private static final String host = "localhost";
        private static final String databaseName = "test";

        private static MongoClient mongo = null;
        private static MongoDatabase db = null;

        public static MongoClient getMongo() {
            if (mongo == null) {
                mongo = new MongoClient(host, port);
            }
            return mongo;
        }

        public static MongoDatabase getDB() {
            if (db == null) {
                if (mongo == null) {
                    mongo = getMongo();
                }
                db = mongo.getDatabase(databaseName);
            }
            return db;
        }

        public MongoCollection<Document> getCollection(String collection) {
            if (db == null) {
                db = getDB();
            }
            MongoCollection<Document> table = db.getCollection(collection);
            return table;
        }

    }
```

I my doing things correctly ? 
is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: The code looks OK (IMHO), the error seems to be related to a missing class. How do you specify your dependencies and which ones do you include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java doc for NoClassDefFoundError at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html is as below.

> The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing
>   class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.

First of all, make sure that the version of MongoDB and Driver are same.

Try using MongoDB Java Driver verison 3.1 or above. I see com.mongodb.client.model.geojson.codecs package in the MongoDB Java docs -http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.1, where as this is not available with version 3.0 - http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0.

Hence the Java driver might be throwing an error with the version that you are using (i.e, 3.0.4).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using something in the 3.x line of the Java driver.  It sounds like you are using 2.13 or 2.14.

Comment: I'm using java driver .3.0.4, perhaps i must connect to mongodb by running  some commands on command prompt !

Comment: That class was added in 3.1 of the driver.

Comment: I added the new version of the driver and this still does not work !